# drush features-list-packages in drupal 8 doesn't include prefix

Tags: 8, drush, features

I've just started using Drush and Features with Drupal 8. I'm running into a point of confusion, and I can't figure out if it's a feature or a bug.

In the past our team prefixed all the site-specific features with some abbreviation, let's say, `whg_`. Then, when I run `drush fl` the features would show up as `whg_calendar, whg_events, etc.` It now appears that features automatically appends the bundle's abbreviation to the feature, great.

The issue is when I `drush fl` I now get a list of features without the abbreviation: `calendar, events, etc.` I can use the feature commands to `update`, `revert`, etc, but I can't use the `pm-` commands to modify the modules, since, they are in fact, prefixed. So, in order to uninstall the module I have to `pm-uninstall whg_calendar`.

Additionally, `drush fu calendar` creates a new feature at `modules/custom/calendar`

This seems like an inconsistent way to work with features. This might be a meta question, but, is this a bug, should I report it to the github project?

Comment: I would recommend reporting this to the Features module maintainers.

Comment: Yes, now that I think I've confirmed it's a bug, I'll report it.

Answer (score 1):

For configuration management in Drupal 8, you don't need to use features, you can use the configuration management module, which outputs .yml files.

The files are saved at sites/default/sync

to export them, use

```
drush cex
```

(drush configuration export)

and to import them use

```
drush cim
```

You can also manually do this from /admin/config/development/configuration

See https://www.drupal.org/documentation/administer/config

Comment: It is in fact true that many sites will be better served by using Configuration management directly, and avoiding features; however, there is still a use case for the features module.  Configuration management is designed for managing configuration changes between different instances of the same site (e.g. dev, test and live). Features is designed for sharing groups of configuration between different sites.

Comment: OK, I didn't know that features was still a thing in Drupal 8.